# GAE endpoint - access_token doesn't authenticate User

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, authentication, access-token

I'm trying to make an authenticated call to a GAE endpoind method from a plain javascript environment (no gapi client), using the steps listed at:
[Google Accounts Authentication and Authorization](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login)

The code is resembling the implementation found in the googleAuth.js file from: [Google Auth (OAuth 2.0) for Titanium](https://github.com/ejci/Google-Auth-for-Titanium).

The code is returning an access_token which is valid for getting user information from googleapis, using:

```html
curl https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=ya29.iA...
```

However, when I'm trying to access a method from an endpoint configured with the same settings (client_id, client_secret) used to get the access_token, I'm receiving a null user parameter. The Authorization header is correctly received in method: "Bearer ya29.iA...".

```js
  @ApiMethod(name = "listGreetingsAuth", path = "listGreetingsAuth")
  public ArrayList<Greeting> listGreetingAuth(HttpServletRequest request, User user) throws OAuthRequestException {
       String text = null;
  if (user == null) {
     UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        User user2 = userService.getCurrentUser();
        if (user2 != null){
            text = "cu:" + user2.getEmail();
        }
        else {
         //throw new OAuthRequestException("Please authenticate!");
         text = "Not authenticated: -" + request.getHeader("Authorization");
        }
  }
  else {
   text = "tu:" + user.getEmail();
  }
    ...
```

Using the endpoint method from the web client (using gapi client.js) is correctly retrieving "tu:<<useremail>>".

I don't know what I'm missing. Isn't the access_token supposed to authenticate the user in the enpoind method?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use Google JavaScript client library as outlined in the Endpoints [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js)?

Comment: Hi Nikita. Yes, I'm using this code from Titanium Appcelerator which doesn't fully support javascript objects.